# ActiveRecord Save Dependent Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to save a model with its dependency models being saved.

```
Model1
    has_many :model2, :autosave => true

Model2
    belongs_to :model1
    has_many :model3, :autosave => true

Model3
    belongs_to :model2
```

I want to save Model1, and have Model2 and 3 save as well. I tried this without and with the autosave feature. What winds up happening is Model1 is saved, Model2 is saved, Model3 is untouched. Is there a way to tell ActiveRecord that for this save I want to save the model and all child models all at once?

As a side note, all 3 are just created and are not in the database. I cannot do .create on the models because I cannot save them until all validation passes and all business logic succeeds (has to be a transaction).

Comment: What happens if you use `:autosave => true` on `Model3` also? Like `belongs_to :model2, :autosave => true`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no proposed methodology to debug this issue, I will just close it as such.